# Does threaded=true in my python chatbot application is enough for thousands of requests?

Tags: python, flask

I am using **threaded=True** in my python flask chatbot application and that's working fine with few people.

But, The real question is my chatbot is going to interact with thousands of people at the same time in that case is it enough to only use threaded=true in my application?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Flask request context handle requests and keeps them separated from one another. As I understand it threads will also be made by your web server when you deploy your app. I think that nginx spawn workers for threads... I do not know for others. If your flask app is written  in a right way ( no unnecessary globals...) It will work fine.

I hope that answer you question?